# Laravel Vue JWT Authentication - How to automatically login the user after login

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt

I can find anything on web getting this done. I understand a token has to be generated before a user can login, but is there a way to automatically log in the user after they register? Here my register method.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users|max:255',
        'password'  => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);
    if ($v->fails())
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'errors' => $v->errors()
        ], 422);
    }
    $user = new User;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();
    return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a package to deal with the JWT authentication? if yes which one?

Comment: tymondesigns / jwt-auth

Answer (score 2):

You are using JWT tokens so after registration you have to send a token belongs to the user which tells other API that this is the logged-in user.

Generate JWT token and return the response with token

> $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
>
> return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'token' => $token], 200);

Comment: Do I have to make some changes here as well?  It's my vuejs, if success, in my register method.    success: function () {
            app.success = true
            this.$router.push({name: 'login', params: {successRegistrationRedirect: true}})
          },

Comment: Yes, you have to save the token in VJS level and set login as true.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below methods

> Auth::loginUsingId(1);

or

> Auth::login($user);